# ActionBar Tabs Navigation with Custom ActionBar view strange behavior

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs, ui-patterns

I'm having this strange behavior with the action ActionBar Tabs showing above the ActionBar.
This happens to be happening when I am setting a custom view for the ActionBar.I'm implementing the Done-Discard pattern using Roman Nurik's example [here](http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/donediscard#donediscard)

This is happening due to the masking of ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME in setDisplayOptions()

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The screen looks like this:
[image]

But when I dont mask the ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME it works fine but the App Logo is displayed. like this.

[image]

This seems to be a bug.Please suggest a fix.I don't want the logo to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution here:

[ActionBarSherlock - Tabs appearing ABOVE actionbar with custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973143/actionbarsherlock-tabs-appearing-above-actionbar-with-custom-view)

and here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327

This seems a little hacky to me but here's the workaround:
Add this piece of code in your onCreate and hide the Home Icon. Now the ActionBar and Tabs work as expected.

Remember not to Disable/Mask the DISPLAY_HOME_HOME in the ActionBar.setDisplayOptions().This will not work if you mask/disable it.

```
View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: may i know is it supported in all version i tried the same but it give me exception i run the program in 2.3.1 version

Answer (score 1):

First set "DisplayShowHomeEnabled" property of actionbar to "true":

actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

and then:

```
View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I hope it helps :)