# android-How to move swipe tab after custom actionbar

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm using swipe tab in my application ,as you can see in this image ,it comes above the custom actionbar .

[image]

this is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        actionbar();

        viewpager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(new myAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
                //agar viewpager safhe ro taghir dad, action bar ham haman ro entekhab kone             
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  // amade ye sakht Tab bash

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionbar.newTab();
        tab1.setText(Z_Farsi.Convert("مشاهده فیلم"));
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionbar.newTab();
        tab2.setText(Z_Farsi.Convert("نظرات"));
        tab2.setTabListener(this);


        actionbar.addTab(tab2);
        actionbar.addTab(tab1,true);

        Bundle bl=getIntent().getExtras();
        onvan=bl.getString("onvan");
        url=bl.getString("url");

        Fragment_playmoview fragment = new Fragment_playmoview();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("onvan", onvan);
        bundle.putString("url", url);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
private void actionbar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View mCustomView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar,null);

        ImageView nDrawer = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        nDrawer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DrawerActivity.open();
            }
        });
        TextView tv1=(TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.setText(Z_Farsi.Convert(onvan));

        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(null);
    }
```

I bring the actionbar() class above but it doesn't work
How can I move my custom actionbar above swipe tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use default actionbar you can do this by including a layout for customised action bar and place it on top of your main activities xml.You should include

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

in your manifest file to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as in this thread:

[ActionBarSherlock - Tabs appearing ABOVE actionbar with custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973143/actionbarsherlock-tabs-appearing-above-actionbar-with-custom-view)

Basically try setting

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

And in onCreate(), to collapse the home button:

```
View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```